# How to define the components of the Poincare group?

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

I know that the Poincare group/inhomogeneous Lorentz group can be defined as:

$$
x^\mu = (t,-x) \\
t \rightarrow t^\prime = \gamma x + \delta t + b^0 \\
x \rightarrow x^\prime = \alpha x + \beta t + b^1 \\
x^{\mu \prime} = R(b) L x
$$
and that it has to be invariant under Minkowski Metric
$$
ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - dx^2 = {ds^2}^\prime = c^2{dt^2}^\prime - {dx^2}^\prime
$$

Usually I could use $$ x^\prime = 0 \\ x= vt$$ and use this in the metric and get the components of the Lorentz transformation, but I am not sure that using translation works too.

Can please someone try to explain to me how to get the Lorentz transformation assuming translation?

Comment: What source has $x^\mu = (t,-x)$?

Comment: Near [duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265521/what-is-the-matrix-representation-of-the-momentum-operator-generator-of-transla).  Few books write the ten  5x5 matrices of the Poincare group, but most decent QFT books write the infinitesimal realizations. Wu-Ki Tung's group theory book certainly does. The linked question illustrates how translations are expressed in matrix form.

Comment: [This](http://cftp.ist.utl.pt/~gernot.eichmann/2014-hadron-physics/hadron-app-2.pdf) might be helpful, or the bottom of p 11 [here](http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/archives/physics251_15/Term%20Project.pdf).

Comment: Whoa, the Wu-Ki Tung book are really good. But what I want to show is that $$ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta $$ are the Lorentz transformation components. Which is just said in the book.
$$ {x}^\prime = \Lambda ^\mu_\nu x^\nu + b^\mu. $$
With lambda beeing the proper Lorentz transformations. But I cant get this result.

Answer (score 1):

Lorentz transformations relate two reference frames whose origins coincide.  If there is a spacetime translation involved, then those two frames are not related via Lorentz transformation.

---

Starting from an **inhomogeneous** Lorentz transformation $x'^\mu = \Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} x^\nu + b^\mu$, consider an infinitesimal displacement $dx^\mu$.  In the transformed coordinates, the inhomogeneous term falls away and you are left with $dx'^\mu = \Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} dx^\nu$, since

$$x'^\mu-y'^\mu = (\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu} x^\nu + b^\mu) - (\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu}y^\nu + b^\mu) = \Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu}(x^\mu-y^\mu)$$

From there, you can proceed as usual to derive the form of $\Lambda$ from physical considerations.

Comment: But the Poincare Group, or the inhomogeneous Lorentz are the set of transformations in Minkowski space consisting of all translations and proper Lorentz transformations.

Comment: @A.Map When you say “Lorentz transformation” without any other precondition, that will be interpreted as a proper Lorentz transformation. The general transformation which includes translations cannot be written in the form $\Lambda^\mu_{\ \ \nu}x^\nu$. They can be realized as 5x5 matrices as referenced by Cosmas in the comments, is that what you’re looking for?

Comment: They can be written in the form $${x}^\prime = \Lambda^\mu_\nu x^\nu + b^\mu$$, right? If it is correct, I want to show that the $$\Lambda$$ term is from the Lorentz transfomartion.

Comment: @A.Map Oh, I see.  I've updated my answer.  The key is to consider displacements, not absolute coordinates, in which case the inhomogeneous term is canceled out.